# UIB tabset is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
<div class="ui-tab-container">
    <uib-tabset>
        <uib-tab heading="Region Wise" index="region" active="region_wise">Tab 1</uib-tab >
        <uib-tab heading="Branch Wise" index="branch" active="state_tab">Tab 2</uib-tab>
        <uib-tab heading="City Wise" index="city" active="city_tab">Tab 3</uib-tab>
        <uib-tab heading="Counter Wise" index="counter" active="counter_tab">Tab 4</uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

No tabs are getting displayed and when I switched to bootstrap tabsets they worked fine but I was not able to switch from 1 tab to another on clicking a button on first tab even though I set the active property of that tab to true from inside the function of the button(when clicked)
"bootstrap": "~3.3.0"
"angular-bootstrap": "~2.3.1"
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include your relevant javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<uib-tabset active="'region'">
    <uib-tab heading="Region Wise" index="'region'" active="region_wise">Tab 1</uib-tab >
    <uib-tab heading="Branch Wise" index="'branch'" active="state_tab">Tab 2</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab heading="City Wise" index="'city'" active="city_tab">Tab 3</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab heading="Counter Wise" index="'counter'" active="counter_tab">Tab 4</uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

You forget to add the `active` directive to the `uib-tabset` and give it a value

> active (Default: Index of first tab) - Active index of tab. Setting this to an existing tab index will make that tab active.

Also you didn't instantiated the `active` values inside your `uib-tab` elements

> Tab index. Must be unique number or string.

So it should be either like this `index="'region'"` (note the single apostrophe inside, index expects an expression!!) or `index="1"`

[plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/IaBCp7xMrbCmwCx1FUeN?p=preview)

Comment: That was understood.I did some playing with it but when I restored it to the above mentioned format it dint work as well.My problem is that it is not getting loaded.I cant see the tabs with the heading.No signs of tabs!

Comment: have you included the `ui-bootstrap` script after the `angular` script in your index.html ?

Comment: Yes Sir. <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the directive **active** inside **ui-tab** must be bound with some boolean variable in your model.

```
<uib-tab ... active="boolean_variable_to_bind">...</uib-tab >
```